# htaccess query string to path not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this: `http://example.com/TEST/user/ticket.php?id=1`

I want this: `http://example.com/TEST/user/ticket/1`

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /TEST/user/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?ticket/(.*?)/?$ /ticket.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /ticket\.php\?id=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?ticket\.php$ /ticket/%1? [L,R=301]
```

What's wrong?

`.php` extension is correctly hidden, but query string instead is not "converted" to path. It gives me:

> 500 internal server error

Comment: Where is this `.htaccess` file located? Your directives suggest it is at `/TEST/user/.htaccess`? What values can your `id` URL parameter have?

Answer (score 0):

The server logs should show you the reason for the error.

One problem here is that in the last line you use a pattern that matches just `ticket.php` and not `ticket.php?id=`

```
RewriteRule ^/?ticket\.php$ /ticket/%1? [L,R=301]
```

Try

```
RewriteRule ^/?ticket\.php?id=([^\&\ ]+).*$ /ticket/$1? [L,R=301]
```

The `RewriteCond` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: how should it be then

Comment: Try just a `RewriteRule` without `RewriteCond`.

Comment: Increase the Logging and see why it doesn't work: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging

Comment: You can't match the query string with the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ (this matches against the URL-path only). The query string is already being matched (and captured into `%1`) by the preceding condition.